# Bash script to shift numbers in txt file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

So I'm quite new to bash scripting and I'm having an issue figuring out a solution to my problem.

So I want to write three numbers to a "ShiftCodeAssociations.txt" and then contents look like:

```
1
2
3
```

However, every time I run this script I want it to shift the numbers so it will put the number at the top to the bottom.

After looking up while loops reading line by line I found this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/ and came up with the following

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/ubuntu/ShiftCodeAssociations.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if [$line = "1"]
  then
        $line = "2"
  elif [$line = "2"]
  then
        $line = "3"
  else
        $line = "1"
  fi
done < $input
```

However, this doesn't work and it outputs

```
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 5: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: [1: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 8: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: [1: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 12: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 1: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 5: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: [2: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 8: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: [2: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 12: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 2: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 5: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: [3: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 8: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: [3: not found
AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 12: AdjustShiftCodes.sh: 3: not found
```

Can someone help me, please :)

Thank you!

Comment: The `[` is not just syntax, it is a command. Like any command, it requires whitespace to separate it from its arguments.

Comment: Once you've resolved the basic problem with "shell scripts are space sensitive", you've also got logic problems to deal with.  You need no space around the variable assignments (as it stands, you're invoking a command like `1` which you don't have — `line="2"` is what you mean). You also aren't echoing any output or otherwise dealing with the modified line.  Be cautious though; you can't read from and write to the same file in simple shell scripts.  As written, your code doesn't generalize well to handle any number of lines other than 3. There are better ways to move the first line to the end.

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Can you clarify if sorting matters to your question? The description of your question and example made me think of the command ''sort -u' which would reverse the string you provided just as you are asking very efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed

```sh
sed -i '1{h; d}; $G' ShiftCodeAssociations.txt
```

GNU awk

```sh
gawk -i inplace 'NR == 1 {first = $0; next} 1; END {print first >> FILENAME}' ShiftCodeAssociations.txt
```

bash

```sh
f="ShiftCodeAssociations.txt"
mapfile -t lines < "$f"
lines+=("${lines[0]}")
unset 'lines[0]'
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" > "$f"

# The rotation can also be done like this:
#    lines=( "${lines[@]:1}" "${lines[0]}" )
```

or

```sh
f="ShiftCodeAssociations.txt"
temp=$(mktemp)
while IFS= read -r num; do
    echo "$(( num % 3 + 1 ))"
done < "$f" > "$temp" && mv "$temp" "$f"
```

Comment: This is for sure a much more elegant solution! (and very nice the `mapfile` never saw it before).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, what this script is doing is not really clear: as it is it will not output anything. Within the if statements you are just assigning the strings `"1"`, `"2"` and `"3"` to the variable `$line` (replacing the initial value which correspond to the line of the file).

You can try using the command `echo` and redirect the value to a file.

Following the script with the correct syntax.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/ubuntu/ShiftCodeAssociations.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  if [[ "$line" == "1" ]]; then
        line="2"
  elif [[ "$line" == "2" ]]; then
        line="3"
  else
        line="1"
  fi
done < $input
```

Bash is a bit peculiar since "spaces" behaves slightly different than in other more sophisticated languages. For example when assigning a variable the form `$line = "1"` does not work since the `$line` would be interpolated and considered as a command (there is a space after).